# Using JSON populated list from django view

Tags: javascript, json, django-views, simplejson

here is my view:

```
def dummy_method(request):
    data = simplejson.dumps({'a': 1})
    return render_to_response('test.html',data)
```

my javascript:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "test",
  type: "GET",        
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {               
    //Popluate combo here by unpacking the json
    alert("0");  // This is the first element of the array sent by the server
  }
});
```

my url:

```
url(r'^test$', 'www.views.dummy_method', name='home'),
```

Comment: Can you describe what your question specifically is? What is going wrong, what did you expect to happen, what happened which wasn't supposed to, or what did not happen?

Comment: i just want to make sure that this alert appears but the alert does not so this means that the code does not reach the success so i just want the code to enter the success and then i will manipulate it

Comment: Your URL doesn't look correct: try `url: "/test/"`. Have you verified that the javascript is definitely running the ajax call? Have you verified that if so, the view is being run on the server?

Comment: the view is working on the server properly and yes it the ajax is working but it never enters the success function any clue ??